# Bankruptcy problem with concrete $E$ and $d$

Tags: game-theory

I have a problem with the derivation of a bankruptcy problem as given [here](https://www.gwern.net/docs/statistics/decision/1985-aumann.pdf) on the page 199 which was computed in a Matlab program with $E=11$ and $d=(10,20,30).$
How was derived the game $(0,0,0,0,0,1,11)$ here ? I believe that the coalitions are ordered like this: $1,2,3,12,23,13,123.$

[image]

Comment: Certainly not, they are ordered in accordance with the unique integer representation of coalitions. Have a look into the manual of the Toolbox MatTuGames in the doc-folder. There you will find more information.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt I have now opened "manual_mat_tugames.pdf" which has 160 pages. Can you specify the page for me where can I find it ?

Comment: See the Section: SOME PRELIMINARIES